# Text selection within dynamically-loaded element in WebKit browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit

I'm having the strangest recurring problem in both Safari and Chrome for Mac. One of my apps has a dynamically-loaded sidebar div which gets populated with an AJAX-loaded form. In Firefox, when I enter text into the contained text area, I'm able to use the browser's Select All feature to select the text. However, in Safari and Chrome, it does nothing.

Also of note: Any static text within that div cannot be selected using the selection cursor.

Now, I'm not entirely sure the fact that the content is dynamically loaded has ANYTHING to do with the issue, and it's very likely that it doesn't. I've looked at the computed styles for all of these elements and I don't notice any -webkit-user-select option being set, which I assumed was the likely culprit.

Are there any other CSS properties which may have an effect on text selection?

Cheers!

Comment: user-select: none; Though I don't know how it would be set by itself. Are you sure that there isn't a transparent element infront of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looking into overlapping DIVs? Perhaps set the z-index of the content div to be higher than any other element.